# Extracting time form JS Date Object

Tags: javascript, date

I have below JS code

```
let options = { hour12: false,  timeZone: 'America/Chicago', timeStyle: 'short' };

let myDate = new Date('2021-06-07T05:46:00.000Z').toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options);
```

The expected output from above is 00:46 as I am using hour12 to false but instead it returns 24:46
which is an invalid time, could someone please highlight what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

use `en-GB` instead of `en-US`

```js
let options = {
  hour12: false,
  timeZone: "America/Chicago",
  timeStyle: "short",
};

let myDate = new Date("2021-06-07T05:46:00.000Z").toLocaleTimeString(
  "en-GB",
  options
);

console.log(myDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is working as expected, would you please help me to understand, why it wasn't working with en-US, and also would you please me to understand why you changed en-UK to en-GB